When creating curves, are more points better? Why?
On the left, I converted the letter "O" into curves. On the right, I have created the same shape with significantly fewer points. When printed, no one would be able to tell the difference. However, the vector program (Affinity Designer in this case) adds more points to create the curves.
For simpler shapes, I would assume that fewer points can be used while a more complex shape would need/require more points. Is there a reason to have more points in a simpler shape?

I have read How to properly place control points on bézier curves and tame those curves? which is about the placement of the points whereas I am asking about the number of points required.
(Note: I use the letter "O" only as an example. My question is for creating curves in general and not solely for converting text to curves.)

Less points is always preferable if there is no discernible difference. Illustrator has a "Simplify Paths" command- not sure if Affinity does or not.

Although having fewer anchor points is generally desirable when creating a design from scratch (especially in font design) because it makes smooth curves easier to achieve, I wouldn't stress about the number of anchor points when automatically converting text to paths. Simplifying won't make any difference, and arguably it could make the paths less faithful/accurate compared to the original. Basically, it would be a waste of time IMHO.
In vector software generally, converting text to paths is always going to give you some additional anchors that are somewhat redundant. The software is splitting up some of the curves with additional anchors to achieve more accuracy.
The exact same thing happens in similar software such as Illustrator, and Inkscape.  I'm not an Affinity user, but it would appear the same thing is happening in Affinity for the same reason.  I have also noticed that the actual number of anchors created is also dependent on the font, as some seem to have more uniform curves than others.

There is no assumption that bezier curves as technology is only for drawing images on screens. Even on screens there might be different technologies that for reasons require different functions.
There are situations where the end application requires you to split the curves. Most notably font rendering requires curves to be split at certain minima and maxima.
Technically you could also need to split items because you need to move from one spline technology and the next like from higher order spline to lower.
Another reason is that your trying to model a mathematical function more accurately. The classical example of this is that. Normal non-rational Beziers can not model a circle. They can approximate it, but its not a circle. So even though you can not visually discern any difference, 5 points would be more accuratey a circle than 4 (and why 2 and 3 look a bit off). You probably wouldn't do this for visual purposes though but could do it for engineering/simulation reasons.
Anyway, if you place points less is almost always better. Since having more points means you have more likelyhood of generating oscillations in the curve. This is probably not a deep problem in 2d graphics. But it is a huge problem in designing surfaces.

There isn't a single right answer to this question
Your goal is to use only as many points as are necessary to produce an appropriately clean curve for the intended application. Your goal should be (IMO as I'm also a programmer) to favor using fewer points over more — but the intended application is the principal problem here.

If you are printing a banner to cover a wall (e.g., a background for a speaker), you'd want more points for larger objects (but not necessarily smaller) since every flaw would be noticeable.
On the other hand, if the goal is a computer screen, fewer points leads to less storage space and less CPU processing to represent the curve because the algorithms for the curves are applied to every point regardless the size of the curve defined by that point.

If you're expecting the object to be scalable cleanly in the small direction, more points can actually lead to errors as the algorithms of each point can collide with one another, leading to unexpected consequences. Then again, if you're expecting it to scale in the large direction, too few points can lead to intersection errors where unexpected V-shaped collisions that aren't visible at smaller scales suddenly become obvious.
Frankly, I've seen both errors scaling text. A well-designed font doesn't have this problem and fonts are a good example of where picking the correct number of points matters.
Summary

Fewer points leads to faster-resolved shapes and lower storage, but they favor objects getting smaller rather than larger.

More points leads to slower-resolved shapes and greater storage, but they favor objects getting bigger rather than smaller.

Too few points means scaling larger can lead to inadequate intersection information. Too many points means scaling smaller can lead to too much intersection information. Scaling outside the intended range of the design in either direction will lead to compromised curves.


When should I take the time to adjust the number of points?
Only if you intend to use the object many times over a variety of scales. I'd never go to that much effort for a one-off unless perfect was being paid for.
Having said all that, algorithms get better and computers get faster, so let me leave you by emphasizing my initial assertion: favor using fewer points over more.

A bezier is size invariant so you dont need more points when its bigger.

@joojaa That's true! If you're only considering one curve segment. The problem occurs at the intersection of two curve segments. I've used fonts that, when expanded to large poster sizes (1,000 points or larger), the curve intersections fail. Regrettably, the system isn't magic and there are reasons for increasing the number of points.

Well it shouldt really happen, but quite a few fonts are desiged so that the points all over the place. Obviously if you want to intersect then you should have points at overlapping intersection otherwise the graphics will tear. Most graphic designers wouldnt do this but for example illustrators shapebuilder will. But fonts are also a special case since the tech has/used to special requirements.

@joojaa Fonts are an easy example, but hardly anything unique. I've used Illustrator's auto-trace too many times to believe that. There's more to this than simply trusting the algorithms.

Fonts are, possibly very old and using the oldest and most restrictive authoring system. Tracing does not do any guarantees against tears. I dont think this was on the radar for most programmer or artist 15 years ago.
